# How can i pass textbox value to ng-repeat in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

1) I have Industry dropdown with code(textbox) .Based on Industry drop down value code will change.

2) I have dynamic add/delete for Movie Name and Name of Director

here we have 3 columns in table Movie Name ,Director ,Industry Code

we can add Movie Name and Name of Director dynamically but Industry Code we need get from above drop down .

when ever we change Industry field we will get one code(if user select tamil we will get code TN). based on Industry dropdown we need to update all Industry Code rows(this column avilable in table)

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Xku9z/1270/)

```
<div data-ng-app data-ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <label>Industry</label>
  <select ng-model="data" ng-options="data as data.name for data in datas">
  </select>
   <label>code</label>
   <input type="text" ng-model="data.code" disabled/>


<ul>
            <li>Movie Name</li>
            <li><input type="text" ng-model="name" /></li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
            <li>Name of Director</li>
            <li><input type="text" ng-model="director" /></li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
            <li></li><li><button ng-click="addRow()"> Add Row </button></li>
        </ul>
         <table> 
            <tr>
                <th>NO</th>
                    <th>Movie Name</th>
                        <th>Director</th>
                        <th>Industry Code</th>
            </tr>

            <tr ng-repeat="movies in movieArray">
                <td><label>{{$index + 1}}</label></td>
                <td><label>{{movies.name}}</label></td>
                <td><label>{{movies.director}}</label></td>
                <td><label>{{movies.code}}</label></td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="movies.Remove"/></td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <div>
            <button ng-click="submit()">Submit Data</button>   
                <button ng-click="removeRow()">Remove Row</button>
        </div>

        <div id="display" style="padding:10px 0;">{{display}}</div>
```

controller:

```
function myCtrl($scope){
 $scope.datas = [{
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Tamil",
    "code": "TN"
  }, {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "English",
    "code": "EN"
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "name": "Telugu",
    "code": "TE"
  }]


     $scope.movieArray =
        [
            { 'name': 'Total Eclipse', 'director': 'Agniezka Hollan' ,'code': 'TN'},
            { 'name': 'My Left Foot', 'director': 'Jim Sheridan','code': 'TN' },
            { 'name': 'Forest Gump', 'director': 'Robert Zemeckis','code': 'TN' }
        ];

        // GET VALUES FROM INPUT BOXES AND ADD A NEW ROW TO THE TABLE.
        $scope.addRow = function () {
            if ($scope.name != undefined && $scope.director != undefined) {
                var movie = [];
                movie.name = $scope.name;
                movie.director = $scope.director;

                $scope.movieArray.push(movie);

                // CLEAR TEXTBOX.
                $scope.name = null;
                $scope.director = null;
            }
        };

        // REMOVE SELECTED ROW(s) FROM TABLE.
        $scope.removeRow = function () {
            var arrMovie = [];
            angular.forEach($scope.movieArray, function (value) {
                if (!value.Remove) {
                    arrMovie.push(value);
                }
            });
            $scope.movieArray = arrMovie;
        };

        // FINALLY SUBMIT THE DATA.
        $scope.submit = function () {
            var arrMovie = [];
            angular.forEach($scope.movieArray, function (value) {
                arrMovie.push('Name:' + value.name + ', Director:' + value.director);
            });
            $scope.display = arrMovie;
        };
}
```

Comment: This can't work. var movie = []; I suspect you mean var movie = {}

Comment: So you need to push the industry code to table along with name and director when adding new entry or do you need to update the entire table's industry code to match the selection?

Comment: push the industry code to table along with name and director if already  name and director and if i change Industry in dropdown that time also we need to update all the rows

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/nymdjf5f/1/     check this

Comment: i change Industry in dropdown that time we need to update all the rows of Industry Code remaining should be same(only we need to change Industry Code) @HussainMohd . now if i change  Industry in dropdown i am not getting any table data...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/nymdjf5f/5/ check this

Answer (score 1):

```js
function myCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.datas = [{
      "id": 3,
      "name": "Tamil",
      "code": "TN"
    }, {
      "id": 4,
      "name": "English",
      "code": "EN"
    },
    {
      "id": 5,
      "name": "Telugu",
      "code": "TE"
    }
  ]

  $scope.change_drop = function(data) {

  }
  $scope.movieArray = [{
      'name': 'Total Eclipse',
      'director': 'Agniezka Hollan',
      'code': 'TN'
    },
    {
      'name': 'My Left Foot',
      'director': 'Jim Sheridan',
      'code': 'TN'
    },
    {
      'name': 'Forest Gump',
      'director': 'Robert Zemeckis',
      'code': 'TN'
    }
  ];
  $scope.selected_row = {
    'val': ''
  }
  $scope.change_drop = function(){
       $scope.movieArray.forEach(function(val, i) {
         val['code']      = $scope.selected_row['val']['code']
      }) 
   }
  // GET VALUES FROM INPUT BOXES AND ADD A NEW ROW TO THE TABLE.
  $scope.addRow = function() {
    if ($scope.name != undefined && $scope.director != undefined && $scope.selected_row['val']['code']) {
      var find = 0
      $scope.movieArray.forEach(function(val, i) {
       
        if (val['name'] == $scope.name && val['director'] == $scope.director) {
          val['code'] = $scope.selected_row['val']['code']
          find = 1;
        }
         val['code']      = $scope.selected_row['val']['code']
      })
      if (find) {
        $scope.name = null;
        $scope.director = null;
        $scope.selected_row = {
          'val': ''
        }
        return
      }
      var movie = {};
      movie.name = $scope.name;
      movie.director = $scope.director;
      movie.code = $scope.selected_row['val']['code']
      movie.industry = $scope.selected_row['val']['name']
      $scope.movieArray.push(movie);

      // CLEAR TEXTBOX.
      $scope.name = null;
      $scope.director = null;
      $scope.selected_row = {
        'val': ''
      }
    }
  };

  // REMOVE SELECTED ROW(s) FROM TABLE.
  $scope.removeRow = function() {
    var arrMovie = [];
    angular.forEach($scope.movieArray, function(value) {
      if (!value.Remove) {
        arrMovie.push(value);
      }
    });
    $scope.movieArray = arrMovie;
  };

  // FINALLY SUBMIT THE DATA.
  $scope.submit = function() {
    var arrMovie = [];
    angular.forEach($scope.movieArray, function(value) {
      arrMovie.push('Name:' + value.name + ', Director:' + value.director+'code:'+value.code);
    });
    $scope.display = arrMovie;
  };
}
```

```css
div {
  font: 15px Verdana;
  width: 450px;
}

ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 2px 5px;
  list-style: none;
  border: 0;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}

li {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
}

table,
input {
  text-align: left;
  font: 13px Verdana;
}

table,
td,
th {
  margin: 10px 0;
  padding: 2px 10px;
}

td,
th {
  border: solid 1px #CCC;
}

button {
  font: 13px Verdana;
  padding: 3px 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div data-ng-app data-ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <label>Industry</label>
  <select ng-model="selected_row['val']" ng-options="data as data.name for data in datas" ng-change="change_drop(data)">
  </select>
  <label>code</label>
  <input type="text" ng-model="selected_row['val'].code" disabled/>


  <ul>
    <li>Movie Name</li>
    <li><input type="text" ng-model="name" /></li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>Name of Director</li>
    <li><input type="text" ng-model="director" /></li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li></li>
    <li><button ng-click="addRow()"> Add Row </button></li>
  </ul>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>NO</th>
      <th>Movie Name</th>
      <th>Director</th>
      <th>Industry Code</th>
    </tr>

    <tr ng-repeat="movies in movieArray">
      <td><label>{{$index + 1}}</label></td>
      <td><label>{{movies.name}}</label></td>
      <td><label>{{movies.director}}</label></td>
      <td><label>{{movies.code}}</label></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="movies.Remove" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <div>
    <button ng-click="submit()">Submit Data</button>
    <button ng-click="removeRow()">Remove Row</button>
  </div>

  <div id="display" style="padding:10px 0;">{{display}}</div>
```

Comment: can u check now?

Answer (score 1):

I think adding an ng-change will do the trick check this
http://jsfiddle.net/nymdjf5f/5/

```
 $scope.changeindustry=function()
        {
        for(var a in $scope.movieArray)
        {
        $scope.movieArray[a].code=$scope.data.code;
        }

        };
```